# Difference between traditional imperative style of programming and functional style of programming

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I have a problem statement here 
what I need to do it iterate over a list find the first integer which is greater than 3 and is even then just double it and return it.

These are some methods to check how many operations are getting performed

```
public static boolean isGreaterThan3(int number){
        System.out.println("WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 " + number);
        return number > 3;
    }
    public static boolean isEven(int number){
        System.out.println("WhyFunctional.isEven " + number);
        return number % 2 == 0;
    }
    public static int doubleIt(int number){
        System.out.println("WhyFunctional.doubleIt " + number);
        return number << 1;
    }
```

with java 8 streams I could do it like

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
integerList.stream()
           .filter(WhyFunctional::isGreaterThan3)
           .filter(WhyFunctional::isEven)
           .map(WhyFunctional::doubleIt)
           .findFirst();
```

and the output is

```
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 1
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 2
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 3
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 5
WhyFunctional.isEven 5
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 4
WhyFunctional.isEven 4
WhyFunctional.doubleIt 4
Optional[8]
```

so total 8 operations.

And with imperative style or before java8 I could code it like

```
for (Integer integer : integerList) {
            if(isGreaterThan3(integer)){
                if(isEven(integer)){
                    System.out.println(doubleIt(integer));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

and the output is

```
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 1
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 2
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 3
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 5
WhyFunctional.isEven 5
WhyFunctional.isGreaterThan3 4
WhyFunctional.isEven 4
WhyFunctional.doubleIt 4
8
```

and operations are same. So my question is what difference does it make if I am using streams rather traditional for loop.

Comment: Traditional approach describes *how* you operate, declarative describes *what* you need as a result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you wrong. Bytecode differs very, very much.

Comment: it must be different cause with functional approach there must be invokedynamic instructions since we are using lamda here.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou The "how/what" dichotomy is just about the level of description: even with FP you say how to achieve a higher goal. For example, what="find the best business prospect", how="filter the set of all prospects by X, then group by Y, then find max on each group, etc.".

Comment: The point of lambda is to not have to write methods or anonymous classes when you just need to specify some logic you don't use elsewhere or is not relevant as a method. You should not create methods just for filtering numbers greater than 4

Answer (score 7):

Stream API introduces the new idea of streams which allows you to decouple the task in a new way. For example, based on your task it's possible that you want to do different things with the doubled even numbers greater than three. In some place you want to find the first one, in other place you need 10 such numbers, in third place you want to apply more filtering. You can encapsulate the algorithm of finding such numbers like this:

```
static IntStream numbers() {
    return IntStream.range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .filter(WhyFunctional::isGreaterThan3)
                    .filter(WhyFunctional::isEven)
                    .map(WhyFunctional::doubleIt);
}
```

Here it is. You've just created an *algorithm* to generate such numbers (without generating them) and you don't care how they will be used. One user might call:

```
int num = numbers().findFirst().get();
```

Other user might need to get 10 such numbers:

```
int[] tenNumbers = numbers().limit(10).toArray();
```

Third user might want to find the first matching number which is also divisible by 7:

```
int result = numbers().filter(n -> n % 7 == 0).findFirst().get();
```

It would be more difficult to encapsulate the algorithm in traditional imperative style.

In general the Stream API is not about the performance (though parallel streams may work faster than traditional solution). It's about the expressive power of your code.

Answer (score 6):

The imperative style *complects* the computational logic with the mechanism used to achieve it (iteration). The functional style, on the other hand, *decomplects* the two. You code against an API to which you supply your logic and the API has the freedom to choose *how* and *when* to apply it.

In particular, the Streams API has two ways *how* to apply the logic: either sequentially or in parallel. The latter is actually the driving force behind the introduction of both lambdas and the Streams API itself into Java.

The freedom to choose *when* to perform computation gives rise to *laziness*: whereas in the imperative style you have a concrete collection of data, in the functional style you can have a collection paired with logic to transform it. The logic can be applied "just in time", when you actually consume the data. This further allows you to spread the building up of computation: each method can receive a stream and apply a further step of computation on it, or it can consume it in different ways (by collecting into a list, by finding just the first item and never applying computation to the rest, but calculating an aggregate value, etc.).

As a particular example of the new opportunities offered by laziness, I was able to write a Spring MVC controller which returned a `Stream` whose data source was a database—and at the time I return the stream, the data is *still in the database*. Only the View layer will pull the data, implicitly applying the transformation logic it has no knowledge of, never having to retain more than a single stream element in memory. This converted a solution which classically had O(n) space complexity into O(1), thus becoming insensitive to the size of the result set.

Comment: I just have one more doubt here about laziness, what is use of intermediate operations being lazy, cause it wont make any difference until I call terminal operation?

Comment: That's the use: you apply the intermediate operation without causing any computation. The stream is now an assembly of your original data and the description of computation you want to perform on it. You perform computation only at the point where you consume the result.

Comment: what difference will it make if I do it beforehand or if I do it when I actually want to perform a terminal operation?

Comment: Because you decouple the description of computation from the choice how to consume it: you can pass the same stream to three different methods, first one collecting into a list, second one just finding the first item (never performing excess computation of the rest), third one calculating average (not wasting RAM on the materialization of the transformed collection). This allows finer-grained factorization of your code than would be available to you in the imperative style.

Comment: I think the difference becomes more clear when you emphasize the fact that you can implement an operation consisting of intermediate steps only and returning a `Stream` to an arbitrary caller, i.e. without knowing the exact terminal operation. The terminal operation can change the way the evaluation works, e.g. being lazy, whereas the imperative programming requires to know the terminal operation and a different terminal operation usually requires an entirely different code for the entire operation.

Comment: @Holger, that's exactly what I wanted to illustrate in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `Stream` API you are describing an operation instead of implementing it. One commonly known advantage of letting the `Stream` API implement the operation is the option of using different execution strategies like parallel execution (as already said by others).

Another feature which seems to be a bit underestimated is the possibility to alter the operation itself in a way that is impossible to do in an imperative programming style as that would imply modifying the code:

```
IntStream is=IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).filter(i -> i > 4);
if(evenOnly) is=is.filter(i -> (i&1)==0);
if(doubleIt) is=is.map(i -> i<<1);
is.findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Here, the decision whether to filter out odd numbers or double the result is made before the terminal operation is commenced. In an imperative programming you either have to recheck the flags within the loop or code multiple alternative loops. It should be mentioned that checking such conditions within a loop isn’t that bad on today’s JVM as the optimizer is capable of moving them out of the loop at runtime, so coding multiple loops is usually unnecessary.

But consider the following example:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("java8 streams", "are cool");
if(singleWords) s=s.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s")::splitAsStream);
s.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str->str.charAt(0)))
 .forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+" => "+v));
```

Since `flatMap` is the equivalent of a nested loop, coding the same in an imperative style isn’t that simple any more as we have either a simple loop or a nested loop based on a runtime value. Usually, you have to resort to splitting the code into multiple methods if you want to share it between both kind of loops.

I already encountered a real-life example where the composition of a complex operation had multiple conditional `flatMap` steps. The equivalent imperative code is insane…

Answer (score 1):

1) Functional approach allows more declarative way of programming: you just provide a list of functions to apply and don't need to write iterations manually, so your code is more consine sometimes.

2) If you switch to parallel stream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) it will be possible to automatically convert your program to parallel and execute it faster. It is possbile because you don't explicitly code iteration, just list what functions to apply, so compiler/runtime may parallel it.

Answer (score 1):

In this simple example, there is little difference, and the JVM will try to do the same amount of work in each case.

Where you start to see a difference is in more complicated examples like

```
integerList.parallelStream()
```

making the code concurrent for a loop is much harder.  Note: you wouldn't actually do this as the overhead would to high and you only want the first element.

BTW The first example returns the result and the second prints.